# pandas: complex filter through groupby

Tags: python, pandas

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'injury':['A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'A'], 'crash_drinking':[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1], 'crash_drugs':[0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1], 'driver_drinking':[1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0], 'driver_drugged':[0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0]})

   crash_drinking  crash_drugs  driver_drinking  driver_drugged injury
0               1            0                1               0      A
1               1            0                1               0      B
2               1            0                0               0      B
3               0            1                0               0      A
4               0            1                0               1      A
5               0            0                0               0      C
6               1            0                0               0      A
7               0            1                1               1      B
8               1            1                0               0      A
```

I want my output to look something like this (column names are changed to differentiate them from the above dataframe):

```
    drinking crash  drinking driver in crash    drugged crash   drugged driver in crash
A                2                        1                 2                         1
B                2                        1                 1                         0
```

Where for the first row, `"injury" = 'A'`, and the following filters are in place:

"drinking crash" is the count where `crash_drinking = 1` and `crash_drugs = 0`;

"drinking driver in crash" is where `crash_drinking = 1`, `crash_drugs = 0`, `driver_drinking = 1,` and `driver_drugs is 0`;

"drugged crash" is where `crash_drinking = 0` and `crash_drugs = 1;`

"drugged driver in crash" is where `crash_drinking = 0`, `crash_drugs = 1`, `driver_drinking = 0,` and `driver_drugs = 1`.

Same for row B, except that's where `"injury" = 'B'.`

Right now I just have a bunch of .loc filters set up:

```
test.loc[(test['injury'] == 'A') & (test['crash_drinking'] == 1) & (test['crash_drugs'] == 0)]
test.loc[(test['injury'] == 'A') & (test['crash_drinking'] == 0) & (test['crash_drugs'] == 1)]
test.loc[(test['injury'] == 'A') & (test['crash_drinking'] == 1) & (test['crash_drugs'] == 0) & (test['driver_drinking'] == 1) & (test['driver_drugged'] == 0)]
```

Etc.

I'd rather do this through groupby, or .apply(), as I think that would be faster than looping through all those queries. But I'm not sure of the proper syntax to do that. Maybe I should do a .groupby() on the "injury" column, and go from there...?

Comment: Your definition of the dataframe does not match its representation (column names are different).

Comment: You mean the columns in my desired output are different from the input? The new columns are not the same as the original columns, they are a combination of the columns, so I wanted to differentiate them. I can change them back but I thought it would be more confusing if they were the same.

Comment: No, take a look at the very first line of code and the dataframe that is printed right after that. They have different column names, which is confusing.

Comment: Also, the result is confusing as well: should `A['drinking crash']` really equal 4? If I follow the logic correctly, it should equal 2.

Comment: Wow, sorry, I thoroughly messed that up. I've corrected the mistakes, I think it should make more sense now.

Comment: Thanks, now it makes perfect sense. What about my answer? It gives the desired output.

Comment: Looks good, thanks-- didn't get a chance to test it till just now. Was hoping it wouldn't require quite so many .loc filters, but that might be unavoidable in this case given the limitation of my data. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
result = pd.DataFrame()
result['drinking crash'] = (test['crash_drinking'] == 1) & (test['crash_drugs'] == 0)
result['drinking driver in crash'] = ((test['crash_drinking'] == 1) & (test['crash_drugs'] == 0) 
                                      & (test['driver_drinking'] == 1) & (test['driver_drugs'] == 0))
result['drugged crash'] = (test['crash_drinking'] == 0) & (test['crash_drugs'] == 1)
result['drugged driver in crash'] = ((test['crash_drinking'] == 0) & (test['crash_drugs'] == 1) 
                                     & (test['driver_drinking'] == 0) & (test['driver_drugs'] == 1))
result = result.astype(int)
result['injury'] = test['injury']
result.groupby('injury').sum()
```

[image: resulting dataframe]